# Parsing strings into two parts (like an email address) C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing

How would one parse a string like `Name@yahoo.com` into a message box as

```
Name: Name
Doman: yahoo.com
```

(without the @ sign)

I know how to set up the message box and such, but am having a tough time trying to figure out how to get the email string split into two separate strings and removing the @ sign in the process.

Edit: How would one split it if the string is defined by the user in a textbox?

As in:

```
 string email = "";
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: `"Name@yahoo.com".Split('@')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [MailAddress Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
MailAddress addr = new MailAddress("Name@yahoo.com");
string name= addr.User;
string domain = addr.Host;
```

Answer (score 3):

Split your string using `String.Split`:

```
string source = "Name@yahoo.com";
var parts = source.Split('@');
var name = parts[0];
var domain = parts[1];
```

Comment: What if the string is declared as empty, so the user enters their own?

Comment: @ChocolateSnow Not sure I've got your point now. You can check if string is empty before splitting and if it is empty - then do whatever you want. Also you can check resulting array length, because if there is no `@` sign in source string, it will be array of length 1 having empty string at position 0.

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var strings = yourFullString.Split('@');

var name = strings[0];
var domain = strings[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `String.Split`

```
string data = "Name@yahoo.com";
var stringArray = data.Split('@');

var name = stringArray[0];
var email = stringArray[1];
```

You can also Use `Regex.Split`

```
string data = "Name@yahoo.com";
string pattern = "@";            // Split on @

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(data , pattern);
var name = substrings[0];
var email = substrings[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

A method without using a separate helper variable would be:

```
var name = data.Substring(0, data.indexOf('@'));
var domain = data.Substring(data.indexOf('@') + 1);
```

Comment: Why do you think that not using a helper variable is better? This code is less clear and more error prone.

Comment: It is not necessarily better it is more or less a matter of taste and I added it for completeness sake. Personally I know people who dislike splitting and using additional helper variables while for others it does not matter at all.

Comment: even this would be less error prone and more clear: `var name = data.Split('@')[0]; var domain = data.Split('@')[1];`

Comment: More clear...possible yes. What do you mean though with less error prone (do you reference there that many people use .indexOf wrongly?)?

Answer (score -1):

Use a built-in class of .Net. It is really easy and you should not to see to `Regular expressions` or methods of `String` class. 
Cause

- there is no exact Regular expression which can parse any email as some emails can have really rare signs like `"'~!,*`.
- It may have a lot of unnecessary code if you will work with methods of `string` class.

It is really easy to use MailAddress class:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailAddress mailAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("BobValery@mail.com");
string address = mailAddress.Address;
string name = mailAddress.DisplayName;
string host = mailAddress.Host;
string user = mailAddress.User;
```